# How to drop an EVENT when curdate() = future date MYSQL

Tags: mysql, events

I am utilizing an EVENT in MYSQL to move records in batches around my database:

```
USE db;
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS eval_1day;
Delimiter $$
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS eval_1day
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS current_timestamp()
DO
  BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO db.t2
      (`upc`,
       `brand`,
       `agency`,
       `policy`)


SELECT 

    db.`upc`,
    db.`brand`,
    db.`agency`,
    db.`policy`
FROM db.t
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 600;
DELETE FROM db.t order by id desc limit 600;

COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So my question is, I want to add into this EVENT query something along the lines of

```
IF CURDATE() = future_date, DROP EVENT IF EXISTS eval_1day;
```

Is this doable and if not in the manner I want, is there an alternative method here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way
is to add ENDS and you end date

```
STARTS current_timestamp()
ENDS '2020-01-31'
DO
```

But you can also add

```
IF '2020-01-31' >= curdate() THEN
    DROP EVENT eval_1day;
END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: Thank you for the help kind stranger.  That was EXACTLY what I was looking for.